# Add permissions to channel for user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've recently added this Discord bot to my server: https://github.com/critcola/discord-auto-grouping

It's working great and I've modified it slightly to ensure it creates a room based on the user's name, with a user limit and under a certain category in my server.

My last edit — which I can't seem to get my head around — is, when the channels are created, to add the user to the permissions and allow them full administrative rights on the channel only.

Below is what I've tried so far, it produces no errors it just doesn't do anything hence I'm now stumped!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
// Check if the user entered a new channel.
if (member.voiceChannelID) {
    const newChannel = member.guild.channels.get(member.voiceChannelID);
    // If the user entered a game channel (prefixed with a game controller unicode emoji), group them into their own channel.
    if (newChannel.name.startsWith(String.fromCodePoint('0x1F3AE'))) {
        newChannel.clone(String.fromCodePoint('0x2501') + member.user.username + "'s Room", false)
        .then(createdChannel => {
            createdChannel.edit({
                bitrate: 96000,
                //position: newChannel.position + 0,
                userLimit: 5,
                parent: '409821646698971136'
            })
            //Set Permissions
            .then(createdChannel.overwritePermissions(member.user.id,{'MANAGE_PERMISSIONS':true, 'MANAGE_CHANNELS':true}))
            .then(createdChannel => {
                member.setVoiceChannel(createdChannel)
                .then(console.log('[' + new Date().toISOString() + '] Moved user "' + member.user.username + '#' + member.user.discriminator + '" (' + member.user.id + ') to ' + createdChannel.type + ' channel "' + createdChannel.name + '" (' + createdChannel.id + ') at position ' + createdChannel.position))
                .catch(console.error);
            })
            .catch(console.error);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    }
}
```

Comment: From [Permissions.js](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/util/Permissions.js), it kinda looks like `MANAGE_PERMISSIONS` is not a real permission. Also can you just do `'ADMINISTRATOR': true`?

Answer (score 0):

You've made a little mistake. As `MANAGE_PERMISSIONS` is an invalid permission, 
 you need to use `MANAGE_ROLES`.